# How can I use Filezilla and vsftpd to write to an AWS EC2 instance of Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: amazon-ec2, filezilla, vsftpd

I use FileZilla and vsftpd on another server and understand that I have to change vsftpd.conf and uncomment the line(s) that say:

```
# Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
local_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to enable any form of FTP write command.
write_enable=YES
```

So, I have that done and have restarted vsftpd but still I am unable to move files to the server. Should I chmod the directory that I am putting things in? That directory is /var/www/html and current permissions are:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan  9 20:13 html
```

I don't know where else to look. It must be something simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to modify files in your web directories, try changing the ownership (instead of the mode) by doing this:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/html
```

The $USER variable will take the value of the user you are currently logged in as.

By doing this, your regular (non root) user now owns the html subdirectories where you are trying to move files into.

It probably a good idea to also modify permissions a little bit to ensure that read access is permitted to the general web directory and all of the files and folders it contains so that pages can be served correctly, use:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
```

Your web server should now have the permissions it needs to serve content, and your user should be able to create content within the necessary folders

Comment: Michael - that did it. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: great, if my answer solved your question, you can "accept" it by selecting big tick. If you think it added value to the community you can upvote with the up button. That gives feedback for other users to go by